# Date difference calcuation in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have weird formatting date and time data, and need to calculate the difference in R. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
TimeStart           TimeEnd
May  1 2016  1:00AM May  1 2016  1:28AM
May  1 2016  1:01AM May  1 2016  1:21AM
May  1 2016  1:00PM May  1 2016  1:13PM
May  1 2016  1:00PM May  4 2016  5:42PM
May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:37PM
May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:14PM
May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:39PM
May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:18PM
```

Comment: Can you add some clarification about your data? Maybe run a `dput` so we can see how the columns are defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `?strptime` to see how to format date/time objects.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- read.table(text = "May  1 2016  1:00AM May  1 2016  1:28AM
                   May  1 2016  1:01AM May  1 2016  1:21AM
                   May  1 2016  1:00PM May  1 2016  1:13PM
                   May  1 2016  1:00PM May  4 2016  5:42PM
                   May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:37PM
                   May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:14PM
                   May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:39PM
                   May  1 2016  1:02PM May  1 2016  1:18PM")

dat2 <- setDT(dat)[ , list(start = paste(V1, V2, V3, V4),
                           end = paste(V5, V6, V7, V8))]
dat2[] <- lapply(dat2, as.POSIXct, format = "%B %d %Y %H:%M%p")
dat2[ , diff := end - start]
dat2
#                  start                 end      diff
# 1: 2016-05-01 01:00:00 2016-05-01 01:28:00   28 mins
# 2: 2016-05-01 01:01:00 2016-05-01 01:21:00   20 mins
# 3: 2016-05-01 01:00:00 2016-05-01 01:13:00   13 mins
# 4: 2016-05-01 01:00:00 2016-05-04 05:42:00 4602 mins
# 5: 2016-05-01 01:02:00 2016-05-01 01:37:00   35 mins
# 6: 2016-05-01 01:02:00 2016-05-01 01:14:00   12 mins
# 7: 2016-05-01 01:02:00 2016-05-01 01:39:00   37 mins
# 8: 2016-05-01 01:02:00 2016-05-01 01:18:00   16 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr,

```
library(dplyr)

       # parse datetimes
df %>% mutate_all(as.POSIXct, format = '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p') %>% 
    # add column with time difference
    mutate(elapsed = TimeEnd - TimeStart)

##              TimeStart             TimeEnd   elapsed
## 1 2016-05-01 01:00:00 2016-05-01 01:28:00   28 mins
## 2 2016-05-01 01:01:00 2016-05-01 01:21:00   20 mins
## 3 2016-05-01 13:00:00 2016-05-01 13:13:00   13 mins
## 4 2016-05-01 13:00:00 2016-05-04 17:42:00 4602 mins
## 5 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:37:00   35 mins
## 6 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:14:00   12 mins
## 7 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:39:00   37 mins
## 8 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:18:00   16 mins
```

or equivalently in base R,

```
df$TimeStart <- as.POSIXct(df$TimeStart, format = '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
df$TimeEnd <- as.POSIXct(df$TimeEnd, format = '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
df$elapsed <- df$TimeEnd - df$TimeStart

df
##              TimeStart             TimeEnd   elapsed
## 1 2016-05-01 01:00:00 2016-05-01 01:28:00   28 mins
## 2 2016-05-01 01:01:00 2016-05-01 01:21:00   20 mins
## 3 2016-05-01 13:00:00 2016-05-01 13:13:00   13 mins
## 4 2016-05-01 13:00:00 2016-05-04 17:42:00 4602 mins
## 5 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:37:00   35 mins
## 6 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:14:00   12 mins
## 7 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:39:00   37 mins
## 8 2016-05-01 13:02:00 2016-05-01 13:18:00   16 mins
```

---

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(TimeStart = c("May 1 2016 1:00AM", "May 1 2016 1:01AM", 
    "May 1 2016 1:00PM", "May 1 2016 1:00PM", "May 1 2016 1:02PM", 
    "May 1 2016 1:02PM", "May 1 2016 1:02PM", "May 1 2016 1:02PM"
    ), TimeEnd = c("May 1 2016 1:28AM", "May 1 2016 1:21AM", "May 1 2016 1:13PM", 
    "May 4 2016 5:42PM", "May 1 2016 1:37PM", "May 1 2016 1:14PM", 
    "May 1 2016 1:39PM", "May 1 2016 1:18PM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L), .Names = c("TimeStart", "TimeEnd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use lubridate for things like this. It is a simple package to use with a consistent naming scheme for parsing the date-times.

```
library(lubridate)
```

First convert the date characters into date time objects using `mdy_hm`

```
df2 <- apply(df, 2, mdy_hm)
```

Then calculate the number of seconds in the duration. It automatically tellw you how many minutes, if there are enough seconds.

```
dseconds(df2[,2]-df2[,1])
```

The result looks like this

```
[1] "1680s (~28 minutes)"     "1200s (~20 minutes)"    
[3] "780s (~13 minutes)"      "276120s (~4602 minutes)"
[5] "2100s (~35 minutes)"     "720s (~12 minutes)"     
[7] "2220s (~37 minutes)"     "960s (~16 minutes)"
```